# Change Windows Mobile 6.1 Theme Programmatically

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, mfc

I am trying to figure out the proper procedure for applying a new tsk based theme file in windows mobile 6.1.

I have tried working off of the page http://www.pocketpcdn.com/articles/changetodaytheme.html But this only changes the background, not the system colors for things such as the top and bottom bars on the screen.

wceload.exe seems to work perfectly for some tsk's and partially for others.

Does anyone know more about tsk files and applying them programmatically in Windows Mobile 6.1?

My application is an open source application, the code is avail;able via read only svn, feel free to check it out @ [google code](http://code.google.com/p/manilla2dcustomizer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution, I don't think it is a universal solution though.

Calling "\Windows\cusTSK.exe \Windows\ThemeName.tsk" changes the top and bottom bars, but does not change all apsects of the theme... so calling wceload.exe and then calling cuTSK.exe in that order seems to be able to change the theme using all tsk files that I have tested.

The cusTSK.exe binary does not exist on the Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional emulator image that you can download from msdn, so I think that this file that exists on custom roms and HTC made devices, that is why I do not think this is a universal solution, but it works for my purposes